# How to actually use different IP's assigned to my dedicated server (windows)?

Tags: windows, ip, routing, windows-server-2012, ipconfig

I have a dedicated windows 2012 server, which includes 5 IP for my use.

The IP group looks like this: 111.111.111.208/29

I access my server via RDP at 111.111.111.210

When I open a browser and check my IP it also shows 111.111.111.210

Is it possible to use a different IP for the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is I added an extra IP in the IPv4 configuration (111.111.111.212)

Then I accessed my server via RDP with that new address (111.111.111.212)

And then I had to remove my old address (111.111.111.210)

And then readd that old address with the following command:

Netsh int ipv4 add address "Local Area Connection" 111.111.111.210 255.255.255.248  skipassource=true

Now I can connect to the old address 111.111.111.210 but it will not be used for outbound connections anymore. And my the browser will now show my new IP as 111.111.111.212

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to actually assign those addresses to your server – find the usual "IPv4 configuration" window, click "Advanced", and you'll find a *list box* where multiple addresses can be configured.

Second, tell the programs which address to use. Servers/services often have an option labelled "bind address" or "local addresses". For client apps you'll likely need third-party tools, such as "ForceBindIP".

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about binding addresses but since chrome browser is the only web app I am using, I was able to solve my problem differently.